# Ethereum LightWallet exception at keystore.generateNewAddress: Cannot read property 'encStr' of undefined

Tags: ethereum

Having an error when running one of the demo html pages of LightWallet (https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet). I am trying the page: "example_demo_video.html" But at the following snippet en exception is thrown!

```
var seed = document.getElementById('seed').value
var password = prompt('Enter Password to encrypt seed', 'Password')
var keystore = new lightwallet.keystore(seed, password)

keystore.generateNewAddress(password, 3)
```

Exception call stack:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'encStr' of undefined
    at Function.KeyStore._decryptString (lightwallet.js:322)
    at KeyStore.isDerivedKeyCorrect (lightwallet.js:303)
    at KeyStore.generateNewAddress (lightwallet.js:579)
    at setSeed (example_demo_video.html:15)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (example_demo_video.html:55)
```

Comment: Added an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/ConsenSys/eth-lightwallet/issues/176